# Google maps iOS SDK showing default options to select polygons

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

[image]

Is there any way to hide this option on map. It started appearing recently by default on google maps.

Google maps iOS SDK version: 1.9.0 as we need to support upto iOS 6.

On clicking it, it highlights the poperty polygons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per details provided by google support, we can disable it using

> isIndoorEnabled

property

```
 mapView.isIndoorEnabled = false
```

At high zoom levels, the Google Maps SDK for iOS will show floor plans for indoor spaces such as airports, shopping malls, large retail stores, and transit stations. Indoor floor plans are integrated into the default map tiles for the 'normal' map type (kGMSTypeNormal), and are automatically enabled when the user zooms in, and fade away when the map is zoomed out.